# How to get the equivalent key and iv in openssl

Tags: node.js, openssl

I wonder how  get the identical  key and  as following within `node js`

```
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc','d6F3Efeq')
```

The cipher object can do  and decrypt for me within auto-derived `key and iv`

But I want  do the AES decrypt/ within other language,

I must got the `key and iv`

I tried the generated result by openssl, but it seems not correct.

```
% openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k d6F3Efeq -nosalt -p
key=EBF856AFF206E3C4C9B55215AE472EF13940EF788911B4BDFABAF0D8A3089C67
 =FC88BC2E2954E6D75B076187AED42926
```

Comment: There's not enough information to help. Plus, `d6F3Efeq` and `d6Ffsdfseq` are different keys. But you might try a `-K` (instead of `-k`). I don't think `-passin` applies here, but you could also try `-passin pass:d6F3Efeq`.

Comment: You need to perform parse the resulting ciphertext (8 bytes magic, 8 bytes salt) and then perform the OpenSSL specific key derivation `EVP_BytesToKey`.